# SmartGWT Dialog setting Height for dynamix text

Tags: dialog, height, smartgwt

Here's the deal, im trying to create a popup window that uses a dynamic text, 
     when the text is too large i would like to cap the height of the window and 
     use a scrollbar instead to navigate through it but it does not seems to be 
     working.

### code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
dialog.setMessage(direttivaDescription);

dialog.setOverflow(Overflow.AUTO);

dialog.setWidth(600);

dialog.setHeight(50);


dialog.setIcon(someIcon);

dialog.setButtons(new Button("OK"));

dialog.addButtonClickHandler(new ButtonClickHandler() {

     public void onButtonClick(ButtonClickEvent event) {

     dialog.hide();

     }

});

dialog.draw();
```

If the text is too large the window height will be resized accordingly. The funny 
 part is that setWidth method seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a container such as `HLayout`, `VLayout`, `DynamicForm` etc. where you can add the message in it then finally add the container in the `Dialog`.

Sample code:

```
VLayout vLayout=new VLayout();
vLayout.addMember(new Label(message));
vLayout.setOverflow(Overflow.AUTO);
vLayout.setWidth100();

...
dialog.addItem(vLayout);
dialog.draw();
```

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: You're most welcome. Ask any question related to Smart GWT. I'll try my best to answer it.